# How to debug that my all error message is not showing in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error, login, messages, code

I have a Magento 2 Store.

So i when i try to login with wrong cred. it just doesn't show me error its just reload the page like this.

[image]

i have switched the theme but there is still the same issue on different theme too.

So i think it will be an issue of Custom Module but the problem is there is many modules inside app/code folder so it will be hard to disable each one by one and enable again.

Is anyone have any idea how to do that in best optimised way.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Have you try different account?

Comment: yes @DhirenVasoya i have tried different account too but still the issue is same. I have tried to disable all the custom module too but still no success.

Comment: After disabling all extension, have you run upgrade and deploy command and then check?

Comment: Yes ran the setup upgrade and then di:compile and then deploy then cleared the cache but still no success.

Comment: Have you check with the theme change?

Comment: yes i have changed and activated the theme LUMA but still the issue is same didn't show any error i have checked error log too but nothing there.

Comment: recently have you perfom any upgrade or something?

Comment: yes magento 1.9 to 2.4 but that i have updated 2-3 months back but don't if it is running at that time or not.

Comment: have you fix this ?